# Can't solve because it need *.dll

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, cgal

I am new to deploy me first app in Qt and C++.

When I do DoubleClick in me exe of debug folder, I have this message.

[image: Error to deploy qt app]

But I don't need this .dll to me app. I add this time ago but now I am trying to deploy and find this error.

I review me project.pro and I comment all lines where it is type CGAL.

I detect that it has this problem when I comment one of this lines.

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../libs/CGAL/bin
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../libs/cgal4.9/auxiliary/gmp/lib
```

Could anyone tell me, what I need to review more and If I need to check any part of configuration on tools of my Qt program.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably it doesn't find some dll of QT libs's dependencies. 
Either you need to deploy your all needed dll into same as your executable output folder:

like such config in .pro config:

```
 QMAKE_POST_LINK += windeployqt  $$DESTDIR/$${TARGET}.exe $$escape_expand(\n\t)
```

either you need to configure your windows PATH env variable to add the needed dll path in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like dependency walker to check why your exe needs the CGAL dll to run.

It can be because of a direct dependency:

```
app.exe -> CGAL-vc140(...).dll
```

or an indirect one:

```
app.exe -> a.dll -> b.dll -> ... -> CGAL-vc140(...).dll
```

In the first case you should have a line in a .pro a .pri file that looks like this:

```
LIBS += -lCGAL-vc140(...)
```

And in the second case:

```
LIBS += -la
```

Removing one line or the other and rebuilding (re-run qmake) should remove the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Get DependencyWalker from http://www.dependencywalker.com and open your .exe. It will tell you all the dependencies you miss.
You have to add them to your setup package to deploy your app.